# PHP - Compare two arrays and if there are duplicates remove all matches

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays:

```
foo
bar
baz
```

and

```
foo
baz
```

I'd like to compare these two arrays and if there are matches, remove **both** matches (not just duplicates) so I end up with an array like this:

```
bar
```

I know that array 1 will always contain `foo`, `bar`, and `baz` and that array 2 will always contain `foo` and `baz`. The entries in the array won't always be in the same order but the contents will stay the same.

Instead of comparing the two arrays I could do something like the solution of [16153948](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16153948), but that would require me to use a (almost) duplicate line for each match I want to remove since the entries are fairly unrelated (can't use regex), which doesn't seem like a good solution.

Comment: Is that output to a new array, or must you remove the duplicates from array 1 and array 2?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [array\_merge & array\_unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660675/array-merge-array-unique)

Comment: If you know that the 2 arrays will always contain those values - `$result = ['bar'];` should do it.

Comment: @NigelRen the issue with that is it's not just those three entries, there's 75. I'd like to match and remove 6 of those entries, but that number may increase or decrease with time.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I don't think so. A comment on that question says "[...] this will only work if the keys are [...] guaranteed to be unique between the two arrays, otherwise array_merge will overwrite." Since the order isn't necessarily the same the keys might not be unique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get the differences of both arrays using [array_diff](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) and then merge them  using [array_merge](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php):

```
$res = array_merge(array_diff($a, $b), array_diff($b, $a));
print_r($res);
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/WtLDP)

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => bar
)
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/FV8DJ) with more different values.

Comment: This works. I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/369608/12553344) to a different question, and the \array_diff() method listed there also works. Is this solution or theirs a better option?

Comment: It is the same array_diff method used a single time and for the current example data it would suffice. Only when there are also different values the other way around you could use another array_diff to get those too and then merge them.